# "Module aw-watcher-window quit unexpectedly."

Tags: applications, error, screen-capture, restart, time-tracking

I use the [ActivityWatch app](https://activitywatch.net/) to track the time that I spend on the computer. I am running v0.12.2 which is the latest version. When I restart my computer, it displays an error message. The error message says, "Module aw-watcher-window quit unexpectedly."

How can I prevent this error from occurring? Please find attached a screenshot of the error message. I also reported this issue to the developer on [GitHub](https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/issues/918).

[image: "Module aw-watcher-window quit unexpectedly."]

Comment: This is likely an issue with the App, not macOS.  Did you check with the developer?  Are there updates?

Comment: @Allan I recall updating recently, but I can check again for an update. I have not yet contacted the developer about this issue.

Comment: @Allan I checked my installation and the website. I am running v0.12.2 which is the latest version.

Comment: @Allan As you suggested, I reported this issue to the developer on GitHub at the following location: https://github.com/ActivityWatch/activitywatch/issues/918